# Would appreciate help on how to identify a burnt component on Asus X555UJ

Tags: lcd, components

I would appreciate help on how to identify a burnt component on Asus X555UJ

On ACTUAL Motherboard : X555UJ Rev 2.0 . but Casing says :X555UA DM059T.

Burnt component on Asus X555UJ : ( Wider Area ) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq87U.jpg

( Detail ) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmh3a.jpg

It is related to powering the LCD backlight as image is faint on screen.

Thanks

Comment: Sniff test normally is a good start.  After that the visual test.  After we that multimeter test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Perhaps the red outlines on the photos are too feint , but the wider area photo shows 2 red rectangles.  The second / detail photo zones in on the chip that has a brown "spurt" at its side. I am hoping someone out there knows specific component and its value for the specified board.

Comment: "am hoping someone out there knows specific component and its value for the specified board." - Impossible to determine without the actual chip in front of us or a schematic of the board.  There a reason you didn't upload the images to the se.imgur account?

Comment: The image should be visible on imgur via the links above. I can see them via my browser. Unfortunately I have no schematic.